# How can I get a certain piece of data in a JSON file from API?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm pretty new to APIs and JavaScript. I was wondering how I could print a piece of data on my website, for example:

I would like to print only the "name" tag on the next launch

https://launchlibrary.net/1.4/launch/next/1

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If that API has the appropriate CORS headers set—which from my testing seems like it does—you can call it using the native browser function called [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

For example:

```js
fetch('https://launchlibrary.net/1.4/launch/next/1')
    // Convert response to JSON
    .then(r => r.json())
    // Show name in console
    .then(data => console.log(data.launches[0].name));
```

You can then use the data to interact with the DOM like so:

```js
fetch('https://launchlibrary.net/1.4/launch/next/1')
    // Convert response to JSON
    .then(r => r.json())
    // Show name to user
    .then(launchData => alert(launchData.launches[0].name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `map` function after take data. You can use `fetch` or `jquery ajax` method to take data from api example below.

Map returns to new array for you if you need just take first element then you can say

```
data.launches.map(x=>x.name )[0]
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "https://launchlibrary.net/1.4/launch/next/1",
            success:function(data){
               console.log(data.launches.map(x=>x.name ));
            }
        });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with pure js

```js
fetch('https://launchlibrary.net/1.4/launch/next/1')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.launches.map(x=>x.name)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I added also pure js fetch example